# How to limit number of lines in Perl

Tags: oracle, perl, pdf

I have a perl subroutine which is printing text from an oracle table on a PDF report and I want to limit the number of lines it writes to 4. Here is the subroutine:

```
sub printTextToPDF{
  my ($left_pos, $line_height, $case_field) = @_;
  my ($field_str, $line_pos) = ('', 0);

  if($case_field =~ /(.*?)\\+$/) {
    $case_field = $1;
  }

  my @field = split /\s/, $case_field;

    for $cnt (0 .. $#field) {
      $field_str .= $field[$cnt];

      if($cnt != (scalar @field - 1)) {
        $line_pos = (rindex($field_str, "\n") > 0) ? rindex($field_str, "\n") : 0;

        my ( $strwidth1 ) = prStrWidth(substr($field_str, $line_pos),'Courier',5);
        my ( $strwidth2 ) = prStrWidth($field[$cnt+1],'Courier',5);
        my ( $totalwidth ) = $strwidth1 + $strwidth2;

        $field_str .= ($totalwidth < 124) ? ' ' : "\n";
      }
    }

    @field = split("\n", $field_str);

    for $pos (0 .. $#field) {
      prText($left_pos, $line_height + (4.5*(scalar @field - ($pos+1))), $field[$pos]);
  }
}
```

I am currently using the `substr` function in oracle SQL to limit the number of characters, but that is not the best way to limit the number of lines. Is there a way I can do it, if so please show me how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your Oracle query, can you do `where rownum <= 4`?

Comment: @Hambone - that will just limit the number of rows. My string will be stored in one row, which I need to print on the PDF report and limit the length to not go over the space provided.

Comment: Gotcha.  I'm interested to see if @SteveCarlson's solution will meet your needs.  If not, please clarify.  I'm pretty sure there is a solution here somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Might this work for you?

```
$count = 0;
for $pos (0 .. $#field) 
    {
    prText($left_pos, $line_height + (4.5*(scalar @field - ($pos+1))), $field[$pos]);
    $count++
    if ($count >= 4)
        {
        last;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If we were playing golf, we could have replaced the last 5 lines with `last if $count++ > 3`